# Prevent edits to an Apps Script project bound to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I have a google sheet where I require users to edit certain cells with all other cells locked and with a tick to reset script button, but I would like to know if its possible to lock the script from being edited, everything works fine just need to lock the script.

Link to script to have an idea: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j6mf3bt3K2TZS3lzhYWLDeoovWiWs1I3lyLHItJCVMg/edit#gid=0

Script below

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.value !== 'TRUE') return;
  if (e.range.rowStart !== 6 || e.range.columnStart !== 6) return;
  let sheet;
  if ('Items' !== (sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName()) return;
  const rangeList = sheet.getRangeList([
    'E182:E189',
    'E148:E152',
    'E156:E163',
    'E167:E178',
    'E66:E76',
    'E80:E104',
    'E108:E125',
    'E129:E133',
    'E137:E144',
    'E26:E36',
    'E40:E51',
    'E55:E62',
    'E9:E22',
  ]);
  rangeList.clearContent();
  e.range.setValue(false);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently (January 2024) no turnkey way to prevent users who have editor access to a Google Sheet from modifying a script project bound to that Google Sheet.

The supported way to use Apps Script code with a Google Sheet so that editors cannot view or modify the code is to implement the script project separately as an [add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons). There is a learning curve, which makes the process impractical with simple script projects such as the one quoted in the question.